# Connecting tables PHP

Tags: php, database, filtering

I'm a number of days busy with a PHP script.

This is what I want:
- People can type their ZIP code. If their ZIP code is in table1 than do .. if their ZIP code is in table2 than do... If their ZIP code is in none of the tables than ...
- I can insert ZIP code with other data example name.

But I don't know how to build this. I have searched on the internet I have tried to get what I have. But the function to search in other tables en than do that. It don't work for me

This is what I have:

```html
<!doctype html>
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<title>Plusgas - Postcode invoeren</title>
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
<link rel="stylesheet"  href="bootstrap/bootstrap.min.css">
<link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Courgette" rel="stylesheet">
<script src="bootstrap/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<style>
body{
    font-family: Courgette;
}
.submit{
  background-color: purple;
  color:white;
  text-size:24px;
  padding: 6px;
  border-radius: 5px;
  border:1px solid white;
  font-size: 24px;
}
.submit:hover{
  background-color: white;
  color: purple;
  box-shadow: 0px 0px 20px white;
}
h1{
 font-size: 14px;
}

td,th{
  padding: 4px;
  text-align: center;
}
</style>
</head>
<?php
$servername = "localhost";
$username="*";
$password="*";
$dbname="*";
$id="";
$postcode="";
$provincie="";
$website="";
$contactpersoon="";

mysqli_report(MYSQLI_REPORT_ERROR | MYSQLI_REPORT_STRICT);

//connect to mysql database
try{
 $conn =mysqli_connect($servername,$username,$password,$dbname);
}catch(MySQLi_Sql_Exception $ex){
 echo("error in connecting");
}
//get data from the form
function getData()
{
 $data = array();

 $data[1]=$_POST['postcode'];
 $data[2]=$_POST['provincie'];
 $data[3]=$_POST['website'];
 $data[4]=$_POST['contactpersoon'];

 return $data;
}
//search
if(isset($_POST['search']))
{
 $info = getData();
 $search_query="SELECT * FROM postcodes WHERE id = '$info[0]'";
 $search_result=mysqli_query($conn, $search_query);
  if($search_result)
  {
   if(mysqli_num_rows($search_result))
   {
    while($rows = mysqli_fetch_array($search_result))
    {
     $id = $rows['id'];
     $postcode = $rows['postcode'];
     $provincie = $rows['provincie'];
     $website = $rows['website'];
     $contactpersoon = $rows['contactpersoon'];
    }
   }else{
    echo("no data are available");
   }
  } else{
   echo("result error");
  }

}
//insert
if(isset($_POST['insert'])){
 $info = getData();
 $insert_query="INSERT INTO `postcodes`(`postcode`, `provincie`, `website`, `contactpersoon`) VALUES ('$info[1]','$info[2]','$info[3]','$info[4]')";
 try{
  $insert_result=mysqli_query($conn, $insert_query);
  if($insert_result)
  {
   if(mysqli_affected_rows($conn)>0){
    echo("Postcode is toegevoegd");

   }else{
    echo("Postcode is niet toegevoegd");
   }
  }
 }catch(Exception $ex){
  echo("error inserted".$ex->getMessage());
 }
}

?>
<body>
 <div class="container-fluid">
   <div class="row">
     <div class="col-lg-4">

<form method ="post"   action="">
 <h1>ID nummer (voor filterern)</h1>
  <input type="number" name="id"  class="form-control" placeholder="ID No. /Automatic Number Genrates" value="<?php echo($id);?>" disabled>
 <div class="form-group row">
 <div class="col-xs-6">
  <h1>Postcode</h1>
 <input type="text" name="postcode" class="form-control" placeholder="Postcode" value="<?php echo($postcode);?>" required>
</div>
<div class="col-xs-6">
 <h1>Provinicie</h1>
 <input type="text" name="provincie" class="form-control" placeholder="Provinicie" value="<?php echo($provincie);?>" required>
</div>
</div>
  <h1>Website</h1>
  <select name="website" class="form-control" value="<?php echo($website);?>">
    <option value="websiteZH">Website Zuid-Holland</option>
    <option value="websiteNH">Website Noord-Holland</option>
    <option value="websiteZL">Website Zeeland</option>
    <option value="websiteUT">Website Utrecht</option>
  </select>
</div>

<div class="col-xs-6">
 <h1>Contactpersoon</h1>
   <input type="text" name="contactpersoon" class="form-control" placeholder="Contactpersoon" value="<?php echo($contactpersoon);?>" required>
</div>
</div>

 <div>
  <input type="submit" class="btn btn-success btn-block btn-lg" name="insert" value="Add">
 </div>
</form>
</div>

    <div class="col-lg-8">
   <h2>Student Data</h2>
<?php
$servername = "localhost";
$username = "*";
$password = "*";
$dbname = "*";

// Create connection
$conn = new mysqli($servername, $username, $password, $dbname);
// Check connection
if ($conn->connect_error) {
    die("Connection failed: " . $conn->connect_error);
}

$sql = "SELECT id,postcode,provincie,website,contactpersoon FROM postcodes";
$result = $conn->query($sql);

echo "<table border='1'>
<tr>
<th>Search ID</th>
<th>Postcode</th>
<th>Provinicie</th>
<th>Website</th>
<th>Contactpersoon</th>

</tr>";

if ($result->num_rows > 0) {
    // output data of each row
    while($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {

      echo "<tr>";
echo "<td>" . $row['id'] . "</td>";
echo "<td>" . $row['postcode'] . "</td>";
echo "<td>" . $row['provincie'] . "</td>";
echo "<td>" . $row['website'] . "</td>";
echo "<td>" . $row['contactpersoon'] . "</td>";

echo "</tr>";


    }
} else {
    echo "0 results";
}

$conn->close();
?>
</div>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Questions seeking debugging help ("why isn't this code working?") must include the desired behavior, **a specific problem or error** and **the shortest code necessary to reproduce** it in the question itself. Questions without a clear problem statement are not useful to other readers. See: [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example.](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Answer (score 0):

I'm not realy sure what you want to achieve, what goes wrong, but for sure i see one problem - your function getData() returns array indexed 1..4. Then you get it in search part and you search for $info[0], and that is never set.

2nd of all - this is dangerous way of coding. If someone mean will use your code, he can use SQL injections. Not to manting, that even by mystake someone can use ' (apostroph) and crash SQL query. You should always escape data passed to queries, ie by using real_escape_string() or prepared statements.